# Is the abstract component in the decorator pattern redundant?

Tags: design-patterns, decorator

I try to understand the Decorator Pattern and after reading it in `"Head First Design Patterns"` a question occured.

[image]

If I just dont use the `abstact component interface` and just let my decoraters inherit from the `Beverage class` I get the same functionality. I dont get for what the `abstract decorator` is good for.

Let me show you how my class structure looks like without the `abstract component` (this is in vb but the statements should be easily translated in any other language):

[image]

Could anyone explain to me, why I need the abstract decorator class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you inherit directly from Beverage, all the decorators class will need to declare and maintain reference for concrete component that it decorates by itself. In your example code, the Milk class needs to maintain reference in variable myBeverage.
- So if you are inheriting directly, it will create code duplication in all decorators class (Milk, Mocha, etc)
- Using common class for all decorators has another advantage is that it provides default implementation for methods defined in Beverage class if necessary, the decorator classes just need to override the methods that it wants to add extension behavior to. E.g. let's assume all your decorators (milk, mocha, etc) have the same price, only description is different. So in CondimentDecorator, it can provide a default implementation for cost() that delegates to concrete component. All the decorators don't need to implement this cost() method anymore